# Using R to match two data frames using codes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes. df1:

| Species | Catch by Year |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 2500 |
| 101 | 1759 |
| 116 | 111 |
| 139 | 178 |

and df2:

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | COD |
| 116 | YELLOWTAIL |
| 139 | BLUE ANTIMORA |
| 144 | CUSK |

and I would like to combine both data frames such that the names from df2 replace the Species codes in df1:

| Species | Catch by Year |
| --- | --- |
| COD | 2500 |
| COD | 1759 |
| YELLOWTAIL | 111 |
| BLUE ANTIMORA | 178 |

I considered using a match function to achieve this but I am quite lost. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `df1$Species<-df2$name[match(df1$Species, df2$code)]`

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your reply. This seems to replace all values in df1$Species with NA.

Comment: Provide a reproducible example. It works on Vinicius data.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <-
structure(list(Species = c(101L, 101L, 116L, 139L), Catch.by.Year = c(2500L, 
1759L, 111L, 178L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <-
structure(list(code = c(101L, 116L, 139L, 144L), name = c("COD", 
"YELLOWTAIL", "BLUE ANTIMORA", "CUSK")), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2,by = c("Species" = "code")) %>% 
  select(-Species) %>% 
  select(Species = name,Catch.by.Year)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Species       Catch.by.Year
  <chr>                 <int>
1 COD                    2500
2 COD                    1759
3 YELLOWTAIL              111
4 BLUE ANTIMORA           178
```